# 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll and use two connection strings

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, exception, database-connection

I am using inside my project 2 different datasets for 2 different connection strings, but when I create and start one of my classes, I get the StackOverflowException.

The code where I get the exception is:

```
public class myObject : EventClass
{
    public myDataPathStruct dataPath = new myDataPathStruct();
    public myData data = new myData();
    public periodDownload myPeriod = periodDownload.All;
    private MainDataSet.tbMyDataDataTable myTable = new MainDataSet.tbMyDataDataTable();
    private tbMyDataTableAdapter myAdapter = new tbMyDataTableAdapter();
    private Downloader download = new Downloader();
    private DBFiller dbfiller = new DBFiller(); 
}
```

I get the exception at the moment that I inicialize the Dataset variables. I use the Connection Strings at the settings and each connection string is declared also in each one of my datasets.

Do I miss something or should I approach this solution of another way?

Comment: The exception is likely caused by code you haven't shown, probably in the constructor of one of classes you are instantiating. Stack overflows are generally caused by infinite recursive calls.

Comment: You're right, it was shown there but the main problem was a recursive constructor that I didn't see. Sorry for the inconvienence.